# Entity Framework Many To Many Relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm using the default ASP.NET profile and membership provider.  I want to create a ASP List View with the name of the user and their role.  When I try using this functionality I get a error:

Code behind:

```
public List<aspnet_Users> GetUsers(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
{
    this.entities.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Roles").OrderBy(u => u.UserId).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows).ToList();
}
```

Page directive:

```
<%# Eval("aspnet_Roles.RoleName")%>
```

It's not working because it's a many to many relationship in the database.  How do I change my code behind method to map across the many to many relationship?

Comment: What do you mean its not working?

Comment: What error do you get? How do you map your entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. [You shouldn't map the membership table](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/)s. The ASP.NET membership API already has [a method to get a page of member data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh1acb34.aspx). You're reinventing the wheel, and replacing it with a version where you can't change the tire.